# Android: Dynamically add custom checkboxes to a tableLayout

Tags: android, layout, checkbox

What should I do to use custom checkboxes if I add my checkboxes dynamically in my code? (On the java code not on the XML files.) I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/tutorial-change-look-of-checkbox-t4553.html), but using it I can't achieve my goal.

For example, I have a `tableLayout` and I want to add a checkbox for each new row I have.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this

```
TableLayout tl=new TableLayout(this);  
 TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);  
 CheckBox chk=new CheckBox(this);  
 chk.setText("Hello");  
 tr.addView(chk);         
 tl.addView(tr);  
 setContentView(tl);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Yes, im doing this to add the checkboxes dinamically, but i cant add custom checkboxes, just the default ones.

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add custom checkboxes try this:

```
StateListDrawable stateList = new StateListDrawable();
int statePressed = android.R.attr.state_pressed;
int stateChecked = android.R.attr.state_checked;
stateList.addState(new int[] {-stateChecked}, new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.check_3)));
stateList.addState(new int[] {stateChecked}, new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.check_1)));
stateList.addState(new int[] {statePressed}, new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.check_2)));
final CheckBox box = new CheckBox(this);
box.setButtonDrawable(stateList);
```